# How to scroll up BottomNavigationBar with last item in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to make scrolling Bottom navigation bar view, which will scroll down when scrolling down, scroll up, when scrolling up, and scroll up with last item of recycler view when scrolling to the end. But I don't know how to implement the last thing. This is my BottomNavigationBehavior class:

```
public class NavigationBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior {

    private float height = 0;

    public final void BottomNavigationBehavior() {
    }

    public NavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(@NonNull @NotNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull @NotNull View child, int layoutDirection) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams paramsCompat =
                (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        height = child.getMeasuredHeight() + paramsCompat.bottomMargin;
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull @NotNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull @NotNull View child, @NonNull @NotNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull @NotNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull @NotNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull @NotNull View child, @NonNull @NotNull View target, int dx, int dy, @NonNull @NotNull int[] consumed, int type) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
            child.setTranslationY(Float.max(0.0F, Float.min(height, child.getTranslationY() + (float)dy)));

    }

    public void setEndOfList(boolean endOfList) {
        this.endOfList = endOfList;
    }


}
```

Can someone help me ?